# Connect to MSSQL through PERL on FreeBSD*

Tags: sql-server, perl, freebsd, freetds

I am tryin to **connect** to **mssql** through **perl** on **freebsd**.
On Linux it was easy:

```
apt-get install libdbi-perl freetds-bin libdbd-sybase-perl
```

After that i create freetds.conf file with settings. Example:

```
[MSSQL]
    host = %my server%
    port = 1433
    tds version = 7.0
```

And its work. For the same logic i tryed:

```
cd /usr/ports/databases/p5-DBI/ && make install clean
cd /usr/ports/databases/freetds/ && make install clean
cd /usr/ports/databases/p5-DBD-Sybase/ && make install clean
```

Then i run same code from Linux:

```
use DBI;

my $hostname = 'MSSQL';
my $database = %my database%;
my $user = %my user%;
my $pass = %my password%;

my $dbh = DBI->connect("DBI:Sybase:server=$hostname;database=$database", $user, $pass);
```

And i get:

```
DBI connect('server=MSSQL;database=%my database%, %user%, %password%) failed: (no error string)
```

I will appreciate for any help.

Answer (score 2):

You also can install packages on your freebsd box using [pkg](https://wiki.freebsd.org/pkgng) tool.
So, something like this:

```
pkg install p5-DBI p5-DBD-Sybase freetds
```

About your perl check-up script, I guess that you need to also include:

```
use DBD:Sybase;
```

And I will give a try to change `DBI:Sybase:server=...` to `dbi:Sybase:server=...`

But if you need make sure, check this url: http://search.cpan.org/~mewp/DBD-Sybase-1.15/Sybase.pm

Hope that my 0.002 helps! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

It seems different versions of Sybase.pm have different DBI->connect arguments parsing logic.

I've just found that Sybase.pm $Id 1.115$ doesn't work with calls of form

```
DBI->connect('DBI:Sybase:server=mydbhost:database=dbname','username','password')
```

(note the colon between 'mydbhost' and 'database') while Sybase.pm $Id 1.44$ perfectly does.
Or is it a difference in DBI?

Posting it here for googlers.